# Java interrupting/stopping Timer

Tags: java, timer, libgdx, collision-detection

[image: Item should get deactived after going through first obstacle]

I have an if statement, that checks if my object (wizard) hit an `item`. If he did, the size of the wizard will change and he should be able to survive 1 collision with an obstacle.

Right now I'm stuck at "surviving 1 obstacle collision", because in my collision method I have set it up so that if `InvulnerabilityActive` is true, then it shouldn't detect collision.

So the problem is that, during the entire duration (9 seconds), no collision with an obstacle is being detected. The wizard just flies through. **How can I change it, so that it doesn't detect collision with the first obstacle and then deactivates the item?**

I thought of using the `Timer.cancel()` method, but as you can see I can only refer to it with the `this` keyword. I can't call `Timer.cancel()` before I use the `Timer` itself.

Here is the collision with the item.

```
try {
    invulnerability = new Rectangle(GameWorld.obstacle1.getX() - GameRenderer.generator2.getValue2(),
            GameWorld.obstacle1.getY() + GameRenderer.generator2.getValue1(), 15, 15);
    if ((Intersector.overlaps(GameWorld.wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), invulnerability))){
        GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActive = true;
        activeItem = true;
        case0 = true; 
        GameWorld.wizard.setWidth(8);
        GameWorld.wizard.setHeight(8);
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        this.cancel();
                        GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActive = false;
                        activeItem = false;
                        case0 = false;
                        GameWorld.wizard.setWidth(16);
                        GameWorld.wizard.setHeight(16);
                    }
                 },
                 9000
        );
     }
} catch (NullPointerException e){
     System.out.println("Caught NullPointerException!");
}
```

Here's the collision with an obstacle method:

```
public boolean collides(Wizard wizard) {
   if (GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActive){
       return false;
   } else {
       return (Intersector.overlaps(wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), barUp)
               || Intersector.overlaps(wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), barDown));
   }
}
```

I know that the problem is due to the if statement, because it just checks whether the item is active or not, but I don't know how to change it to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check collisions first. If collision detected - check `InvulnerabilityActive`. If it is `true` - reset it to `false` and return false. On next collision `InvulnerabilityActive` will be false and collision will be detected.

```
public boolean collides(Wizard wizard) {
    if (Intersector.overlaps(wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), barUp)
            || Intersector.overlaps(wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), barDown)) {
        if (GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActive) {
            GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActive=false;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There may be problem like "wizard flies through obstacle and collisions are constantly detected". In that case: add extra field `bool InvulnerabilityActivePending` to `GameRenderer`. Add `GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActivePending = true;` next to `GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActive = true;`. And use this code:

```
public boolean collides(Wizard wizard) {
    if (Intersector.overlaps(wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), barUp)
            || Intersector.overlaps(wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), barDown)) {
        if (GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActive) {
            GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActivePending=false;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActive=GameRenderer.InvulnerabilityActivePending;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Instead of  resetting `InvulnerabilityActive` on collision start, we reset it when collision ends.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate it, but it somehow detects collision in both cases all the time. I'm experimenting with your code a bit (changing the booleans to true or false). If I find the solution I'll mark it as the correct answer :)